# Is it possible to set PlaceAutocompleteFragment dropdown as font family

Tags: android, android-layout, listview

Is it possible to set dropdown list as font family:

[image: Is it possible to set dropdown list as font family]

I am using PlaceAutocompleteFragment ,In this When I type something the dropdownlist need to be shown in roboto-medium or any font family .

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion is to don't go for it if it's not much necessary. For your question, Google provides [Place Auto Complete Service](https://developers.google.com/places/web-service/autocomplete) which you can use to have your task done. But it's very complex and long method.

You can follow [this](http://codetheory.in/google-place-api-autocomplete-service-in-android-application/) tutorial. It uses `AutoCompleteTextView` and `TextView` on which you can easily apply your font either using custom views or setting `Typeface`.